# having trouble with redirects

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I'm using Django nonrel with App Engine and having an issue with redirects.

Very simple redirects in my view handlers:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):

    if check_if_user_needs_to_import(request.user):

        return redirect("user_welcome")
```

Are not redirecting properly in App Engine but rather returning this message in the browser:

**Status: 302 FOUND Vary: Cookie Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Location: http://site.appspot.com/user/welcome/**

If I enter the URL in again in the browser manually, it loads just fine.  This appears to only be an issue when using the redirect() function, any view using render_to_response() works fine.

Additional info:
I've tried both a redirect('name_of_view') - which would call the reverse URL lookup as well as a redirect ('/path/to/url/') which should get resolved by the redirect() function that is native to django.

Both cases are not working

Comment: Where does the redirect function come from?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're outputting text to the response before Django sends its own response. Check your code for `print` statements - more likely than not you're calling print, which you should never do in a WSGI app. The output from print gets sent before any output from your Django app, and thus gets treated as the beginning of the response. Headers sent by Django get output to the body instead, as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things that might help:

1. Is this happening in multiple browsers? HTTP status 302 is the correct Status for a redirect, maybe you've got some debugging mode / addon enabled that is changing how this is processed by your browser?.
2. Is there a reason you're using a relative URL path? Why not use something like:

`return redirect('/user_welcome')`

Comment: The [normal Django redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) performs a reverse URL lookup if the argument is a URL name, as here, so it's not a URL path at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and finally found the root cause.

In whatever redirect function you're using, you need to make sure that the printed output is of the form

> "Status: 302 Found\nLocation: http://www.someurl.com\n\n"

Without the two line breaks **"\n\n"** at the end, your redirection will **NOT work** in production (although it will work on the development server).

Regarding Nick's comment: it is true that you should rely on your framework rather than using sys.stdout.write or print to output your own stuff. Yet some people love to have a clear (low-level) understanding of what's going on under the hook, and building your own little CGI is sometimes necessary for specific needs. But as Nick said, mixing prints *and* a framework at the same time will obviously lead to major issues :-)